# How to get data from third table in eloquent relationships eloquent many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-7

I  am using Eloquent ORM and I have Book model which connect to BookCategory model and BookCategory connect to Category. The l'm problem facing is how to include data from third table in eloquent relationships?

```
Book
    id
    name
    
Category 
    id
    name
    type
    
BookCategory 
    id
    book_id
    category_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say for example you want to get all the books of a certain category:
assuming your pivot table name is **Book_Category**
in your **Category model**:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Book', 'Book_Category', 'category_id', 'book_id');
}
```

and you can eager load category books like :

```
$categories = Category::get()->load('books');
//OR
$categories = Category::with('books')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you are looking for the pivot attribute. This makes additional columns of the intermediate table available.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns